Bought ticket using 2nd first name
I booked a ticket to SA and bought it using my second first name. My name on the passport is:

First name: "Asher Aharon"
Last name: "Gross"

And I bought the ticket under the name "Aharon Gross". There are no typos and the name appears on the passport, but it's not the first one that's written there. Has anyone encountered this issue? Do you have any idea if I will get in trouble for this mistake?
